# how should i pass the primary key from a link

Tags: django

In my django template for user profile, I have a link for Edit profile template. But Its giving no reverse found error.   .This is my html template from where i m passing my pk from model UserProfile which is user. I am not able to pass the primary key for using it in reversing function (this is the error I guess). Also How can I call the primary key in the variable to pass it in the template ? 
      Button

this my views.py

```
class NewUserProfileView(FormView):
template_name = "visit/user_profile.html"
form_class = UserProfileForm

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.save(self.request.user)
    return super(NewUserProfileView, self).form_valid(form)

def get_success_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return reverse("main:home")

class EditUserProfileView(UpdateView):#Note that we are using UpdateView and not FormView
    model = UserProfile
    form_class = UserProfileForm
    template_name = "visit/user_profile.html"

def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])

    # We can also get user object using self.request.user  but that doesnt work
    # for other models.

    return user.userprofile

def get_success_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return reverse("main:home")
```

this is my urls

```
url(r'^profiles/new/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', NewUserProfileView.as_view(), name="new-user-profile"),
url(r'^users/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/', EditUserProfileView.as_view(), name="edit-user-profile"),
```

this is the error`Reverse for 'new-user-profile' with keyword arguments '{'pk': <SimpleLazyObject: <User: sid>>}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: enter code here['profiles/new/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']`

Comment: The full traceback will show you where the error is coming from. I don't think you've included that code in your question.

Comment: Also, note that your view appears to let users edit any profile. If you only want users to edit their own profile, you can remove `pk` from the URL and use `request.user` in the view. You might find `LoginRequiredMixin` useful as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be beter if only the current user can edit his own profil.
In you model, make sure you define something like this :

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ......
```

An then, you can call `request.user.profile` on any views and templates